# need help to solve variable scope issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium

I am unable to access `names` array inside `driver.executeScript`. Please suggest a solution;

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
  By = webdriver.By,
  until = webdriver.until;
var driver = new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();

var flow = webdriver.promise.controlFlow();
var names = ["name1", "name2"];
var len = names.length;
var j = 0
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  flow.execute(function() {
    console.log(names[j]); //this works fine.
    driver.executeScript(function() {
      //console.log(names[j]);  //this gives errror [WebDriverError: unknown error: names is not defined]
      //console.log('testing'); //this never logs
    });
    j++;
  });
}
```

Comment: as written, that problem is unpossible. I could understand if  `names[j]` were undefined, because `j` would end up being 2 before any asynchronous code in executeScript callback was run (assuming that's asynchronous of course), but you say the error is that `names` is undefined ... that's just not possible

Comment: Seconded. This seems like nonsense. I suggest you try to recreate this error in a JSFiddle - I just can't believe that the error you're reporting is really occurring as you describe it.

Comment: I cannot reproduce it on jsfiddle because it used chrome web driver. I even tried cloud9 ide but that also not worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the function with a parameter, and pass names into it;

```
for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
    flow.execute(function(){
        console.log(names[j]); //this works fine.
        driver.executeScript(func(names[j]))
        j++;
    });
}

function func(name) {
    console.log(name);
    console.log('testing');
}
```

Better to evade accessing global variables, try to pass variables & return them to keep a readable & maintainable code.

Comment: Why would accessing the OP's global variable as shown in the question give an error?

Comment: It shouldn't, but somehow the driver might have an isolated scope but my answer solves it without caring about that, right?

Comment: Not sure why 3 down votes.. I also suspect isolated scoping here. @bureaquete answer solved the problem. Note: It took little longer for to reply because I was trying to create a working demo of this issue . I tried cloud9, runnable.com/ etc but no luck.. If you think it is unpossible then I request you to try to reproduce on your system.

Answer (score 1):

Note: Thank you @bureaquete for you answer. This also worked for me.

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
    By = webdriver.By,
    until = webdriver.until;
var driver = new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();

var flow = webdriver.promise.controlFlow();
var names = ["name1","name2"];
var len = names.length;
var j=0
for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
    flow.execute(function(name) {
    return function(){
        var str = console.log(name);
    }
    }(names[j]));
j++ 
}
```

Comment: @trieven Can you check this? You have had this issue right? jsbin.com/boholukafa/edit?js,console,output With my answer you get the correct log, but also an error is it? Also if you can approve my edit, I will upvote your question